# Zoom a div/canvas element in angular on click

Tags: angular, canvas, chart.js, angular5, ng2-charts

Trying to achieve [zoomooz](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/#settings) plugin like functionality in Angular . Since npm does not support zoomooz. Is it possible to have same functionality i.e. animated zoom on click. I am using Angular 6 with ng2 charts and want to zoom the div/canvas section on click and back to normal

Refer demo [url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example) here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example